# How to produce detail, not summary, report sorted by count(*)?

Tags: sql, count, oracle11g

Oracle 11g:

I want results to list by highest count, then ch_id. When I use **group by** to get the count then I loose the granularity of the detail. Is there an analytic function I could use?

```
 SALES
 ch_id desc customer
 =========================
 ANAR  Anari   BOB
 SWIS  Swiss   JOE
 SWIS  Swiss   AMY
 BRUN  Brunost SAM
 BRUN  Brunost ANN
 BRUN  Brunost ROB     


Desired Results
count ch_id customer
===========================================
3   BRUN   ANN
3   BRUN   ROB
3   BRUN   SAM
2   SWIS   AMY
2   SWIS   JOE
1   ANAR   BOB
```

Comment: Have you considered having a subselect with a group by to retrieve the counts? This way you could add it as if it was a column on your main select. Also, can you post your select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the analytic count(*):

```
select * from
(
select count(*) over (partition by ch_id) cnt, 
       ch_id, customer
from sales
)
order by cnt desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select total, ch_id, customer
from sales s
inner join (select count(*) total, ch_id from sales group by ch_id) b
on b.ch_id = s.chi_id
order by total, ch_id
```

ok - the other post that happened at the same time, using partition, is the better solution for Oracle.  But this one works regardless of DB.